# Can SikulixIDE run while concurrently running Java-based sikulixapi.jar programs

Tags: java, eclipse, sikuli, buildpath, sikuli-ide

I have downloaded `sikulisetup[...].jar`, which installs perfectly on Windows 7 64 bit.  The verification test at the end of setup run perfectly, as does `SikulixIDE`.  All good so far.

If I close `SikulixIDE`, open `Eclipse`, create a project and include `sikulixapi.jar` in the build path, I am pleased to be able to write and run a test program using Sikuli constructs.  Still good so far.

If I now open `SikulixIDE`, then jump back to Eclipse and try to run that same test program, it fails.

> [error] RunTimeINIT: extractResourceToFile: /sikulixlibs/windows/libs32/JIntellitype.dll
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\SikulixLibs_201801131607\JIntellitype.dll (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)

That list goes on for a total of 12 dll's that are being used by another process.

Of course the Java program does not run, and that's the problem.

**I would like to be able to have SikulixIDE open while developing in Java.**  What steps would I need to do in order to make this possible?

Comment: Can I inquire as why do you need them both open? Is this just for convenience or you are trying to execute tests from both?

Comment: The reason to have both running is for convenience of developing the Java app.  With the Eclipse IDE alone, I have no easy way to capture and visualize images.  The Sikuli IDE allows me to capture and visualize images.